# how to convert NSString into NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

hi i am new to iOS so please help me ..

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {

        NSDictionary *segueDictionary = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];
        NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
        NSString * string=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[segueDictionary valueForKey:@"vendor_data"]];}
```

the output is

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert = "Get Upto 50% Off ";
        sound = default;
        "vendor_data" =         {
            cat = "Baby & kids";
            "closing_hours" = "09:00 PM";
            latitude = "28.57089323";
            longitude = "77.32666539";
            "offer_desc" = "Get Upto 50% Off On All Kids Clothing.";
            "offer_id" = 1128;

            "offer_in_percentage" = "Get Upto 50% Off ";
            "offer_item_name" = Lilliput;
            "offer_valid_upto" = "2015-10-30";
            "opening_hours" = "10:00 AM";
            "phone_no" = "*********";
            pincode = 0;
            rating = 0;
            "sub_category" = "Clothing,Footwear";
            title = "Offer Of The Day";
            "vendor_address" = "***********";
            "vendor_id" = "lliputkids.com";
            "vendor_location" = "*****";
            "vendor_name" = Lilliput;
            "vendor_type" = shop;
        };
    };
}
```

this coming from push notification data

```
NSString * string = {
cat = "Baby & kids";
"closing_hours" = "09:00 PM";
latitude = "28.57089323";
longitude = "77.32666539";
"offer_desc" = "Get Upto 50% Off On All Kids Clothing.";
"offer_id" = 1128;
"offer_in_percentage" = "Get Upto 50% Off ";
"offer_item_name" = Lilliput;
"offer_valid_upto" = "2015-10-30";
"opening_hours" = "10:00 AM";
"phone_no" = "********";
pincode = 0;
rating = 0;
"sub_category" = "Clothing,Footwear";
title = "Offer Of The Day";
"vendor_address" = "shop.no- 6, sun market";
"vendor_id" = "illiputkids.com";
"vendor_location" = "*******";
"vendor_name" = Lilliput;
"vendor_type" = shop;}
```

this data is in string format but i want in dictionary format
i am getting data in string format.
so please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: from which api you get this?please provide. may be your are missing something

Comment: Thanks for help. edit the question please see

Comment: please give the NSLog(@"%@",userInfo).

Comment: may be [segueDictionary valueForKey:@"vendor_data"] will return a dictionary

Comment: i can confirm after getting value of "userInfo"

Comment: i am edit please see

Comment: it is not "userinfo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with this.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    NSDictionary *segueDictionary = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
    NSDictionary *vendorDic = [segueDictionary valueForKey:@"vendor_data"];
    NSString *vedorAddress = [vendorDic valueForKey:@"vendor_address"];
}
```

**Note:**  in {key:value,key:value} is dictionary formate.but value itself may be a dictionary. i.e  {key:{key:value},key:{key:value,key:value}}

Comment: beacuse i am sure "vendor_data" return a dictionary

Comment: NSLog(@“vedorAddress:%@”, vedorAddress);//shop.no- 6, sun market //you will see

Comment: thanks it's success .. but i want now one thing ? why down voting ?

Comment: because they think this data has come from webservice. so blindly convert with "NSJSONSerialization". unfortunately, they did not know push notification does not retun NSData, it returns NSDictionary directly (may be nested dictionary in your case). You may also download vote which are wrong answer. accept /upvote on write answer. so that other may find the right answer eassily. i am also upvoting you as you are right.

Comment: can you tell me the difference b/w "valueForKey"and"valueForKeyPath"

Comment: valueForKeyPath is used when you key contains period(.). For example,  [vendorDic valueForKey:@"vendor.address"];

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are misinterpreting the JSON format.

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Now if you do following NSLog statement

```
NSLog(@"%@",[json objectForKey:@"sub_category"]);
```

It will give you:- Clothing,Footwear

Answer (score 1):

The `userInfo` parameter of `didReceivePushNotification` returns an `NSDictionary` object.

You can get the `vendor_data` dictionary directly with

```
NSDictionary *vendorDataDictionary = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"vendor_data"];
```

or with subscripting

```
NSDictionary *vendorDataDictionary = userInfo[@"aps"][@"vendor_data"];
```

The method `valueForKey:` is a special KVC method. The standard method to get an object for a key is `objectForKey:`

Answer (score 1):

When you send a remote notification, its payload is formatted in JSON. Roughly explained, it's just all your objects put together in dictionaries & arrays so you can have a clear hierarchy of your objects in the payload.

What you're doing now is just putting that JSON in a string, and instead of having separate objects (arrays and dictionaries containing objects), you have one long string containing all of them.

You need to do the following

- Make sure you send a valid formatted JSON in your notification payload. I don't know how you're sending it so I can't really help you there.
- Once you receive the push, you have a `userInfo` dictionary which you can navigate using `:objectForKey`. This is your JSON, already transformed as an Objective-C object.

You should see your complete structure in the dictionary. Objects and keys, with the proper hierarchy.

**If you see one single string in your `aps` key or other custom key, then you're sending the data wrong**

But if you have

- aps

  - alert
  - message
  - sound
- YourCustomKey

  - a custom object

    - another custom subobject
  - etc.

With that kind of structure in your `userInfo` then it means you're good to go. It's easy to find with a breakpoint on the first line of your notification handling and look at what's in `userInfo`.

Then just look at whats in there and fetch it manually, but if you created the notification payload yourself (which you probably did) then you should know which arrays/dictionary contains what objects, and just fetch it manually.

```
//I'm just giving EXAMPLES : 
NSDictionary *corePayload = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
NSDictinoary *firstLevel = [userInfo objectForKey:@"vendor_data"];
float latitude = [[firstLevel objectForKey:@"latitude"]floatValue];
```

and like that you can fetch anything and everything else.

Note that from what you showed, your content is not formatted properly, some of your keys have "" and some don't, which is not normal. So I suggest you go have a real look at what you're sending, and follow all my steps carefully. And if your first step is not correct, don't go to the next step ;)

Hope you'll find what you're looking for !

Comment: Good ! You can mark an answer as correct then :) Clic the big V under the score of the answer.

Comment: but i want now one thing ? why down voting ? what is wrong  in question?

Comment: I didn't downvote you so I don't know what the others thought :(